# How do I fix the autofocus on a Polaroid Sun 660?

Tags: autofocus, repair, polaroid, instant-camera

I need help with one Polaroid Sun 660.

It seems that autofocus is not working at all. After investigation on internet I noticed that this camera has a four- disc lens, so every time you press the shutter button, sonar calculates and the camera chooses the right lens for the given distance. In my case all my photos are blurred and if I press the shutter button (*using flash or not*) the internal lens are not moving.

I was searching for a repair manual or instructions, but unfortunately I cannot find any such documents. Please advise if you know how to repair this. Removing the front cap I was not able to correct the problem. I probably have to go deeper, removing more parts of the device but, without advice or a *repair** manual I will never be sure what I am doing.

Also the problem is not related to power—I have used different cartridges and the problem persists.

Comment: How fresh are the batteries?

Comment: @MichaelC The battery for this camera is in the film pack, and in my experience will be strong enough to operate the electronics, including flash, and photo ejection motor for many cycles after the film from the pack is gone.

Comment: How old is the film pack?

Answer (score 2):

You can find a teardown of a similar model at iFxit. Sadly the content is too vast to copy it over, so you will have to cope with an external link - however, the model shown here does not include the sonar autofocus, so it may not be as helpful to troubleshooting your issue:

https://www.ifixit.com/Device/Polaroid_One-Step_600